# trying to retrieve a list of fields in an entity

Tags: cakephp-4.x

i am searching for a method to retrieve all fields of a given entity in cakePHP-4. The only way I figured out is like to use the extract method like

```
$values = extract($fields);`
```

this needs an array "$fields" with the fields i want to have the data in it. My idea was to get a list of fields to figure out what fields my entity consists of.

The reason for this is that i try to write my own behavior to log changes in tables. So and due to planning a behavior, i don't know the fields

any ideas or am i on the wrong track.

Many thx,

Christian

Comment: Please post values of $fields

Comment: What's your use case for not actually knowing what fields are in your entity? There are situations where this makes sense, but not very many, so this sounds a little bit like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You might look at the implementation of functions like `getVisible` and `getHidden` to get some inspiration on how to make your own function for this. You might also look at [querying the table schema](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/schema-system.html#accessing-column-data) for the list of columns.